# Add DNS options to systemd-resolved /etc/resolv.conf

Tags: systemd, resolv.conf, systemd-networkd

I am using `systemd-networkd` and `systemd-resolved`. I have `/etc/resolv.conf` being a symlink to `/run/systemd/resolve/stub-resolv.conf` as [recommended](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd-resolved.service.html#/etc/resolv.conf).

I guess that `/run/systemd/resolve/stub-resolv.conf` must be auto-generated, so I would like to know if there is a way to add custom DNS options so the generated file includes them. I'm talking about options like this one: `options single-request-reopen`.

Comment: I would never recommend a symlink over the real thing. Those could have use mostly for multi-version compatibility. My /etc/resolv.conf is my actual resolve. No pseudo-stuff involved. If there's a symlink involved, you will have to edit the actual target of that link.

Comment: @Overmind Are you using systemd-resolved?

Comment: You should not need that option when using systemd-resolved. Actually you should never need that option, and if you do, you should instead fix or replace the offensive firewall hardware which caused the problem.

Comment: Hi @MichaelHampton, thanks for your comment. Could you please explain why I "should not need that option when using systemd-resolved"?

Comment: I think I ran into the same issue as @VincentOlivertRiera requiring that option due to slow DNS resolutions. It only took about a year to finally click that I needed to disable IPv6 (I don't use it on my network). After I did that DNS resolutions are working correctly without needing that option.

Comment: That libc option would not be useful, because it would only be used by requests from libc to the systemd stub resolver. The systemd resolver has completely other code and options. https://github.com/systemd/systemd/tree/master/src/resolve

Comment: The simple, limited "good-enough-for-most-cases and dumb users" systemd-resolver does not implement options. If you need options remove the /etc/resolv.conf symlink and create the file with content as needed (see resolv.conf(5) man page). Also make sure, that your /etc/nsswitch,conf does not contain 'resolver' - i.e. should look like `hosts:  files [SUCCESS=return] dns`.